# R match.call : how to pass a variable to this function?

Tags: r

I'm using the `osqp` package, in which there is an `osqpSettings` function, which code can be found [there](https://github.com/cran/osqp/blob/master/R/params.R) (you can just run this code ithout installing the package if you want, the result is the same). Calling :

```
osqpSettings(verbose = TRUE)
```

or :

```
osqpSettings(verbose = FALSE)
```

works as expected.

But calling any of these :

```
my_verbose = TRUE
osqpSettings(verbose=my_verbose)
osqpSettings(verbose=1>0)
osqpSettings(verbose=eval(1>0))
osqpSettings(verbose=eval(my_verbose))
```

does not work with the following error :

```
Error in checkpar(inpars[[nm]], defaultOsqpSettings[[nm]]) : 
  l'objet 'pairlist' ne peut être converti automatiquement en un type 'logical'
Called from: checkpar(inpars[[nm]], defaultOsqpSettings[[nm]])
```

(the french part translate to 'object cannot be automaticaly converted to a type' ).
I suspect this is the `match.call()` method that this function uses that does not accept code in it's parameters. How can i pass a variable as a parameter (without calling the function if a `if(my_verbosity)`...).

Comment: `debugging in: checkpar(inpars[[nm]], defaultOsqpSettings[[nm]])
debug at /tmp/RtmpPxtz0W/R.INSTALL3472504ea137/osqp/R/params.R#53: {
    l = switch(typeof(r), integer = as.integer(l), double = as.numeric(l), 
        logical = as.logical(l))
    if (length(l) != 1 || is.na(l)) 
        return(r)
    l
}
Browse[6]> length(l)
[1] 1
Browse[6]> str(l)
 symbol my_verbose`, so to check what the symbol evaluates to? Just taking note here.

Comment: I'm sorry @Chris, i did not understood your question ? I cannot modify the function in the package, so i need to pass `TRUE` or `FALSE` to it since it evaluates parameter in such a weird way, as you notice, and `my_verbose` is a symbol, i need to pass the evaluationof this symbol. maybe it's unpossible to have the symbol evlauation before mtch.call catches it ?

Comment: `Browse[6]> s
debugging in: typeof(r)
debug: .Internal(typeof(x))
Browse[7]> s
exiting from: typeof(r)
Error in as.logical(l) : 
  cannot coerce type 'symbol' to vector of type 'logical'`,

Comment: Is the desired need to be able to pass either TRUE of FALSE to osqpSettings depending on the thing being tested?